# ValueError: too many values to unpack in sklearn.make_classification

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a file called `one_dataset.py`which contains a function to generate a synthetic dataset. This is the code:

```
#Generating synthetic datasets
from sklearn import datasets

def create_dataset():
    data, labels = datasets.make_classification(n_samples=200,n_features=4,n_classes=2,flip_y=0.01,shuffle=True)
    return data
    return labels

if __name__ == "__main__":
   create_dataset()
```

I am importing `one_dataset.py` in another file called `two_split.py` so that I can use the created dataset here and split it into training and testing data.The file `two_split.py` looks like this:

```
import one_dataset
import sklearn

try:
    data, labels = one_dataset.create_dataset() 
    print data  
    print labels

except ValueError:
    print "Oops! Too many values to unpack! Lighten up, please!"
```

It catches the ValueError which says too many values to unpack. 
Also, no such error is shown when I try to print `data` and `labels` in `one_dataset.py`.

I would like to know why this must be happening and how to fix it.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the return in your `create_dataset` function to `return data, labels`.

**Rationale:**
Your function `create_dataset` exits after the first return, only returning `data`. When you call the function in the try/catch block you are expecting two values, i.e. `data` and `labels`, however only `data` is returned.

Hope this helps.